# Find data using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I've been trying to retrieve some data using BeautifulSoup.

```
<div class="chartAreaContainer spm-bar-chart">
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Advertising&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 40%" title="">40%</div>
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Media Planning &amp; Buying&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 35%" title="">35%</div>
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Branding&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 20%" title="">20%</div>
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Event Marketing &amp; Planning&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 5%" title="">5%</div>
</div>
```

How to get their data-content name and their percentage.

I am trying `.text` but it gives only the percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select the attribute of the element by its name `['data-content']` - *Cause question is not that detailed, this answer just point into direction.*

##### Example

```
html = '''
<div class="chartAreaContainer spm-bar-chart">
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Advertising&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 40%" title="">40%</div>
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Media Planning &amp; Buying&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 35%" title="">35%</div>
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Branding&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 20%" title="">20%</div>
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Event Marketing &amp; Planning&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 5%" title="">5%</div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('.custom_popover'):
    print(f"{e['data-content']}: {e.text}")
```

##### Output

```
<b>Advertising</b>: 40%
<b>Media Planning & Buying</b>: 35%
<b>Branding</b>: 20%
<b>Event Marketing & Planning</b>: 5%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `parsel`:

```py
from parsel import Selector

html = """
<div class="chartAreaContainer spm-bar-chart">
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Advertising&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 40%" title="">40%</div>
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Media Planning &amp; Buying&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 35%" title="">35%</div>
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Branding&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 20%" title="">20%</div>
    <div class="grid custom_popover" data-content="&lt;b&gt;Event Marketing &amp; Planning&lt;/b&gt;" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" role="button" style="width: 5%" title="">5%</div>
</div>
"""

selector = Selector(text=html)

# regular for loop
for result in selector.css(".grid.custom_popover::text"):
    print(result.get())
    
# or list comprehension
list_result = "\n".join([result.get() for result in selector.css(".grid.custom_popover::text")])
print(list_result)
```

Outputs:

```
40%
35%
20%
5%

40%
35%
20%
5%
```